# set value to state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React, and I have a question of set state, this is the code:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
                return{
                    prevVal: prevState.currentVal,
                    currentVal: 'DIGIT LIMIT MET'
                }
});
```

In this code, the **prevVal** in my project will be updated to **'DIGIT LIMIT MET'**, but I want it to be the last **currentVal** which is prevState.currentVal.

```
this.setState({
                    prevVal: this.state.currentVal,
                    currentVal: 'DIGIT LIMIT MET'

});
```

In this code , the problem will not appear, but according to React document, it can not make sure that the **this.state.currentVal** is the prevState.currentVal.

How to solve this problem perfectly? Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 this.setState(
      prevState => {
        const prev = prevState.currentVal;
        return {
          prevVal: prev,
          currentVal: 'DIGIT LIMIT MET'
        };
      },
      () => console.log(this.state)
    );
```

try this.

Comment: I want the prevVal to be set to prevState.currentVal, and at the same time, I want to set the currentVal to 'DIGIT LIMIT MET', but the problem is that the prevVal ends up being set to 'DIGIT LIMIT MET' instead of the previous currentVal that I want.

Comment: This is still wrong, but when I didn't use React's strict mode which is default in WebStrom IDE, the problem was solved.